# Dynamically created Qt component cannot access parent

Tags: javascript, qt, qml, qt-quick

I am dynamically trying to add Columns to my UI and then anchor them with the parent and nearby element, however parent is always null.

```
columns[i] = Qt.createComponent("Column.qml");

columns[i].createObject(rectangle1,{id : "column".concat(i), "anchors.left" : name, "width" :getcolwidth(rectangle1) });
```

Here `anchors.left` is column0 and in the Column.qml file, I have

```
anchors.leftMargin: 15
anchors.bottom:parent.bottom
anchors.bottomMargin: 5
anchors.top: parent.top
anchors.topMargin: 5
```

The parent should point to rectangle1 but instead it points to null.

Comment: It's a lucky guess but shouldn't it be `"anchors.fill"`? As `anchors.left` requires xxx.left/right not just id.

Comment: @Nadarian name actually contains column0.right, the actual code, `name = "column".concat(i-1).concat(".right");`

Comment: Well then for i=0 your previous column doesn't exist

Comment: @Nadarian i starts at one, I tried removing the name param completely and it still didn't work